# UICollectionView cleanup before disappearing

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionviewlayout

I am having a UICollectionViewController as the root controller in a navigation controller. So this UICollectionViewController is not released / rebuild when I move to other controllers.
I had a quite a few troubles with the combination of "never released" of the controller / NSFetchedResultController / UICollectionView / UICollectionViewLayout. Here is my situation -

- I use the collection view to list all my items in database;
- the collection view should be updated with my item changed;
- the other controllers would update / delete / insert items;
- there is also a backend process to update the items

**Since both NSFetchedResultController / UICollectionView maintains data states, and the database kept changing (because of upserting data), these data states could be out of sync from time to time.** I have spent lots of time to make them consistent. However, since all my data is in local db, it seems much better approach just to clean up data/cells when the view disappears and rebuild it when appearing again.

Does anyone know how to cleanup UICollectionViewController when the view disappears? In my case, I might want to release NSFetchedResultController / remove the event listening to database / release the data cached in the collection view.  Thanks!

Comment: Any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if the question is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: This must be a hopeless question then :).